# Science fiction book involving AI augmented humans, a vampire, a colonised planet, a massive living blob, blind human pilots, and more

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, vampire, artificial-intelligence

There's a series of books I read, probably 10 years or more ago, that I just can’t seem to pinpoint.

The timelines jump about a lot, so it’s hard to figure out the order, but here are some things I recall:

1. there were AI augmented humans (I’ll call the haimans like Neal Asher)
2. there was a male vampire -like haiman who sucked the “energy” out of other augmented, he had a name like “fernando”, Spanish or italian
3. he was beaten and left behind some egg-like thing that was picked up by a female haiman some years later and she became infected with vampire tendencies
4. this section was set on a future colonised planet
5. something occurred that resulted in the female haiman absorbing others physically and becoming a massive living blob that covered the planet
6. there was a grand scheme going on across time with good and bad guys
7. there were baddies with black eyes that took over some humans
8. an advanced group of human pilots that were blind as a result of travel through “hyper-space” - they lived in some golden space outside our universe
9. A German woman character fleeing Nazis through Switzerland and to UK
10. heroes across time meeting on the moon in jade green bodies to discuss their next steps
11. I recall the author wrote another series of books where there was an underground society, a very hierarchical class system based on how deep underground you lived, flying homes for the billionaires, and the hero had lost his arm below the elbow - I never got into that one so much.

Any direction would be great ... it was quite unique.

Comment: Sounds like the author hoped to land an Uwe Boll movie deal. There are even Nazis.

Answer (score 6):

I Have the Answer! I was going crazy also trying to find this series and stumbled across your post, which filled in some details I was missing and got me there!

The books you are looking for are by John Meaney and are set in the 'Pilot' Universe, which are tied together by the Capital P 'Pilots', who are post-humans that are able to travel/think in mu-space (they have exceptional abilities).

There are two trilogies and one stand alone 'future history' novel. The first book published, 'To Hold Infinity' covers your points 1-5 and details the origin of the 'Anomaly' (mysterious and frightening entity) that appears in 'The Nulapeiron Sequence' ('Paradox', 'Context', 'Resolution are the books in this trilogy).

Your points 6-10 are from 'The Ragnarok Trilogy' ('Absorption', 'Transmission', 'Resonance'), which features 3 characters names Ulfr, Gavriela and Fulgor, whose various incarnations/lives are chronicled across time and they meet in the far future in bodies of living crystal.

Although these books had one or two reprints back in the early 2000's, they are currently out of print and mostly only secondhand copies can be had on amazon or elsewhere (although ebooks are available from various online vendors).

The Author John Meaney has stayed active all these years, released some other series, novellas etc. You can check out the Author's website here: https://www.johnmeaney.com/books.html

Answer (score -2):

Firefall  the consolidated book or blindsight and echopraxia for the individual editions

Comment: Welcome to SF&F!  Could you add a little bit of description of these books, and what about them makes them good candidates as a match?  This would help us today, and would help others later who might be searching for this also.

Comment: Most of the points in the question are not in Firefall. I think only the first two points sort of resemble something from it.

Comment: I haven't read Echopraxia, but the only similarities to Blindsight are that the setting is sci-fi and there are beings called vampires. Blindsight does not even depict (human) inter-stellar travel, and nothing in the OP matches its plot.